# Getting value from listview control

Tags: c#

Need help selecting the value from custID column in the ListView so that I can retrieve the value from the database and display it in the TextBoxes.The SelectedIndex not working in c#

Thanks

http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/133/listview.jpg

My Code

```
private void yourListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yourListView.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;
    //get selected row
    ListViewItem item = yourListView.Items[yourListView.SelectedIndex];
    //fill the text boxes
    textBoxID.Text = item.Text;
    textBoxName.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
    textBoxPhone.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
    textBoxLevel.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
}
```

Comment: do you use winforms or wpf?

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get a compile-time error, a run-time error, or does the actual behaviour not meet your expected behaviour.

Comment: Have you done any _cut and paste_ with `yourListView` in the designer? If so, the event handler is not mapped any more to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, unless you reassign it.

Comment: just small proposal. you can set property FullRowSelect=true for your ListView :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ListView doesn't have property `SelectedIndex`. You should use `SelectedItems` or `SelectedIndices`.

So you can use this:

```
private void yourListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yourListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        return;    

    ListViewItem item = yourListView.SelectedItems[0];
    //fill the text boxes
    textBoxID.Text = item.Text;
    textBoxName.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
    textBoxPhone.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
    textBoxLevel.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
}
```

I suggested here that property `MultiSelect` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

C# and WPF use this:

```
private void lv_yourListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
e)
{
    if (yourListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        return;    

     var item = lvb_listInvoices.SelectedItems[0];
     var myColumnData = item.someField; //use whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of the changes you made?

Comment: you should always try and use 'var' keyword, since you are working with objects